# Catching nested exception of type EJBException

Tags: java

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is:
        com.emirates.jfoundation.exception.ServiceException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is: com.emirates.jfoundation.exception.ServiceException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
com.emirates.jfoundation.exception.ServiceException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at weblogic.utils.StackTraceDisabled.unknownMethod()
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        ... 1 more
Caused by: EvaluationException [oldEvaluationRatesDTO=null, **newEvaluationRatesDTO** =ShipmentEvaluationRatesDTO [id=null,
```

I need to read the values in `newEvaluationRatesDTO`. How do I catch **EvaluationException** from the above stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find a specific exception in a nested chain, you can do so by looping on `Throwable.getCause()`. So a method like this will extract the required exception (if it exists):

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends Throwable> T getNestedExcetpion(Throwable caught,
         Class<T> exceptionType) {
    while (caught != null) {
        if (exceptionType.isInstance(caught))
            return (T)caught;
        caught = caught.getCause();
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can then use this in a `catch` clause:

```java
    try {
       // do something that may throw
    } catch (Exception e) {
        EvaluationException myerr = getNestedException(e, EvaluationException.class);
        if (myerr != null) {
            // extract info from myerr
        }
    }
```

If the top level exception is an `EJBException`, [it seems that some implementations of J2EE do not use `getCause()` to retrieve the nested exception from the `EJBException`](https://www.fokkog.com/2013/05/ejbexception-getcausedbyexception.html).

To work around that issue, you might want to catch it like so:

```java
    try {
       // do something that may throw an EJBException
    } catch (EJBException e) {
        EvaluationException myerr = getNestedException(e.getCausedByException(),
             EvaluationException.class);
        if (myerr != null) {
            // extract info from myerr
        }
    }
```

Comment: myerr is coming as null even though we have EvaluationException  in the stack trace.

Comment: If an exception of type `EvaluationException` is available from a `getCause()` call on the stack represented by the chain of `getCause()` calls, then the code above will find it. I suggest debugging through the code and making sure that the data you expect to be there is indeed there.

Comment: I cannot debug due to some reasons. I can only put print statements. Anything I can print which would help to analyze this.?

Comment: You may want to make sure that the `getCause()` return value from the first exception is not null (or maybe just add a print statement for each iteration in `getNestedException()`).

Comment: EJBException myerr = getNestedException(e, EJBException.class); -- Only this is getting caught. ServiceException or EvaluationException  is not getting caught.

Comment: Looking a bit into `EJBException`, I stumbled into this article: https://www.fokkog.com/2013/05/ejbexception-getcausedbyexception.html - it implies that with some `EJBException` implementations, `getCause()` doesn't actually work and you need to use another method to access the nested exception. Maybe you should try to call `getNestedExcetion()` with the result of `getCausedByException()` of the original `EJBException` to start the drill down.

Comment: I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```java
catch (EJBException e) {
   if (e.getCause() != null && e.getCause() instanceof EvaluationException) {
       //do something
   } else {
       // do something
   }
```

Comment: It doesn't get into this catch (InvocationTargetException e) block.

Comment: edited, try to nested try-catch blocks to handle your Exception

Comment: e.getCause() is coming as null.